# STS not picking up Open JDK 11 JRE

Tags: java, eclipse, java-11

I'm trying to add `open jdk 11` on Spring Tool Suite.
I know already discussed this kind of issue here but i did not get right solution for my problem so posted again.

These are the steps I have done:

```
STS -> Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs -> Add -> Standard VM -> JRE Home -> Browsing downloaded OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_windows_hotspot_11.0.4_11 version
```

When i try to add it on my STS, i'm getting

```
Target is not a JDK root. System library was not found.
```

It works well for java `jdk 8` and automatically detecting jre but not working for `Java 11`

1. STS Version: 3.8.4 Release
2. Eclipse Base Version: Neon.3 (4.6.3)

[image]

Comment: What's the base version of Eclipse?

Comment: @nitind Eclipse Neon.3 (4.6.3)

Comment: Java 11 didn't exist until late 2018. Neon 4.6.3 is from 2017. Use a version that came out after Java 11. A new one came out just yesterday.

Comment: @nitind so you meant to say that i should upgrade my sts or eclipse so that automatically detects JRE ?

Comment: Yes. Unless u yo our have a specific reason to use an older version, use the current one.

Comment: I would like to do java development in java 11 instead of java 8 so is there any alternate way to use java 11 in existing sts. whether any configuration change will make it work.

Comment: It's not something I've explored. *Why* are you tied to this older version?

Comment: @nitind, thank you, its working in Spring tools 4

Comment: Spring Tools 3 and 4 are very different.

Comment: I my case I installed STS but don't find Java  under STS -> Windows -> Preferences ->  What to do ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it correctly, but with the wrong version. Java11 support was added with version 3.97:

https://docs.spring.io/sts/nan/v397/NewAndNoteworthy.html

So you must either update STS or do with a Java version less than 11.

Comment: thanks for your help. I'm clear. whether java 10 will support ?

Comment: I think not, even 3.9 had problems with version 9.